# make a function match a right candidate depending on two variables - R

Tags: r

I try to make couplemaker function according to this data

```
girlfriend = c('Sue','Julie','Lora','Lora','Julie')
boyfriend =  c('Sam','John','Peter','Chris','Sam')
goodfeeling = c(88,   78,    63,     51,    40)
couple = data.frame(girlfriend,boyfriend,goodfeeling)
```

With the data above, I want to match the best boy to the girl.

```
A = 'Julie (Sam|John|Peter)'
```

to be

```
A
[1] 'Julie (John)'
```

In order to deal with this string, the code below is so usful.

```
gsubfn("\\(([^)]+)", ~paste0("(", paste(couplemaker(unlist(x)), collapse="|")), A)
```

However, important function is couplemaker() I should make.

```
couplemaker = function(A){couple$boyfriend[which.max(couple$goodfeeling*(couple$boyfriend %in% A))]}
```

This code chooses a boyfriend with the best goodfeeling but not corresponding with girlfriend.

To make my purpose clearer, these are the desirable sets I aim to make.

```
Paris = 'Sue (Peter|Sam|Chris)'
US = 'Lora (Peter|Chris|Sam)'
```

to be

```
Paris
[1] 'Sue (Sam)'
US
[1] 'Lora (Peter)'
```

Answer (score 1):

would this be a sufficient workaround? `group_by` girlfriend and then get the best pair and then `paste`

```
library(dplyr)
do.call(paste,couple %>% group_by(girlfriend) %>%
                         summarise(boyfriend[which.max(goodfeeling)])
)

library(data.table)
do.call(paste, couple[, boyfriend[which.max(goodfeeling)], by = .(girlfriend)])

# [1] "Julie John" "Lora Peter" "Sue Sam"
```

Comment: Well, what I aim to do is to remove less promising candidates in a string.

Comment: @Rcoding yeah but this also does the sme other way around right?

Comment: Ryt! brilliant way to group couples though.